# How to recognise which hand (left or right) an input device has been configured for

Tags: javascript, browser, configuration, d3.js

If a user is, for example, right handed, there is no point having lateral menus on the left side of the screen - and vice versa.

For ease of use by instrumentalists, I'd like to configure a highly interactive browser display to match the hand (left or right) for which a user's input device (for example mouse) has been configured.

I could of course just query the user, but would prefer -at least initially- to pick up a system setting. I see no indication that this is possible, but nothing lost in asking...

I'm trying to avoid jQuery, so would prefer approaches using javascript, css3 or (better) directly using d3.js. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: one idea could be the left/right mouse buttons functions, but I honestly don't know how to get them recognized in d3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, by "right-handed" vs. "left-handed," you mean whether the mouse primary and secondary buttons are configured as left, right (normal) or right, left (reversed), there is no way in JavaScript to get that information. That's a system configuration setting. All you'll get from JavaScript is a primary button or secondary button click, no indication of whether the click was the right button or the left button.

I don't think this is what you want, but it is possible in JavaScript to tell whether the user's language is a "right-to-left" language (e.g. Arabic or Hebrew).

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that seems clear enough, and you're correct, language orientation is not relevant.